# Wordpress; installed lamp, have localhost, but no login

Tags: 17.10, lamp, localhost, wordpress

I installed the AMP in LAMP (already on Ubuntu) for wordpress -- and upon the initial installation & completion I got the wordpress login page, logged in, saw the control panel & stuff; logged out & haven't been able to get back ever since.

When I go to localhost, I get an index page (instead of a login page). Within the `/var/www` directory, I have an `/html` dir. & within that is my `/wordpress` directory. I've fiddled with the `000-default.conf` file in my `/etc/apache2` directory & have changed the document root back & forth some – currently it’s looking at `/var/www` – which is giving me html as the parent directory on my localhost page (the wordpress folder is showing up under the parent & I can click to it; just leads to a blank page). I don't have a server alias (which I've seen in a couple different threads).

I know this is going to be a stupid question: but how do I get back to the login page so that I can create a site? I'd like to have a couple different sites & have seen a couple methods for doing that, but it seems like I should figure out this first.

I did the original setup on 17.04 & like 2 days later was the 17.10 upgrade. I don't know if that is important but there seem to be some issues with the upgrade over all & I've been having some issues myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

localhost/login/

or

localhost/admin/

Comment: i tried both of those urls & on both I got 'requested URL ______ was not found on this server. Am I just skipping a step somewhere? Do I need to use my terminal to launch php or apache2 first? is it just that I'm not logging into stuff in the correct order & that is what's causing me not to find the page?